# How to set Auto-pause delay on for SQL Database? Unexpected error occured

Tags: azure-sql-database

I would like to set Auto-pause delay on for SQL Database. Zone redundancy is disabled.
So I select "Enable auto-pause", set 1 hour and press Apply.

I get a strange error:

```
Failed to scale from General Purpose: Serverless, Gen5, 4 vCores, 
250 GB storage, zone redundant disabled to General Purpose: 
Serverless, Gen5, 4 vCores, 250 GB storage, zone redundant disabled 
for database: my-dev-sql-db-sandbox.
Error code: .Error message: An unexpected error occured while 
processing the request.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, you can switch to serverless compute tier only under the vCore model which provides a wide range of configuration controls and offers Hyperscale/Serverless to automatically scale your database based on your workload needs.

When the scaling operation is failing with aforementioned error, this most likely due to a serverless limitation. For instance, enabling auto-pause for a serverless database is not supported if long-term retention (LTR backups) or geo-replication is enabled.

The following features do not support auto-pausing, but do support auto-scaling:

Geo-replication (active geo-replication and auto-failover groups).
Long-term backup retention (LTR).
The sync database used in SQL Data Sync. Unlike sync databases, hub and member databases support auto-pausing.
DNS alias created for the logical server containing a serverless database.
Elastic Jobs, when the job database is a serverless database. Databases targeted by elastic jobs support auto-pausing, and will be resumed by job connections.
In case any of these features are in-use, then auto-pausing must be disabled and the database will remain online regardless of the duration of database inactivity.

For more information regarding Serverless, you can refer to Azure SQL DB documentation: Serverless compute tier - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs

I hope you find this article helpful. If you have any feedback please do not hesitate to provide it in the comment section below.